# LU decomposition needed for this problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

Hello why do we even do LU decomposition to find the solution?

Suppose we have this system of linear equations:

[image]

Why do we need to do a LU decomposition to solve this problem?Cant we solved by reducing A to a upper triangular matrix using Gauss elimination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gaussian elimination is performed on the augmented matrix $[A | b]$, that is $b$ must be known. LU is a *factorization* method that performs Gaussian elimination on $A$ (no $b$). You can then solve the system $Ax = b$ for any $b$ using the LU factorization of $A$ that was computed once and for all.

Comment: To add, LU decomposition is faster for solving linear systems with the same coefficient matrix $A$ once found…

Answer (score 0):

You must first notice that NOT ALL matrices can be written in LU form. Row changes may be needed, so the correct form for any matrix is that there exists a permutation matrix P such that PA=LU. Now we see the usefullness of LU factorization. Let Ax=b be the original system and A=LU. Then LUx=b. Set $L^{-1}$b=c. Then we obtain Ux=c which is a triangular system which is almost automatically solved! In practice there is not much difference between the two methods because in Gauss elimination some kind of triangularization is involved too! They are similar processes. But we all prefer Gauss elimination!